# Problem reading accented characters in PHP

Tags: php, encoding

Got a strange problem in PHP land. Here's a stripped down example:

```
    $handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        echo $line;
    }
    fclose($handle);
```

As an example, if I have a file that looks like this:

```
Lucien Frégis
```

Then the above code run from the command line outputs the same name, but instead of an e acute I get :

```
Lucien FrÚgis
```

Looking at a hex dump of the file I see that the byte in question is E9, which is what I would expect for e acute in php's default encoding (ISO-8859-1), confirmed by outputting the current value of default_charset.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

As suggested, I've checked the windows codepage, and apparently its 850, which is obsolete (but does explane why 0xE9 is being displayed the way it is...)

Comment: I'm not sure how to set it (or which sets it), but what encoding is your shell/OS/terminal using?

Comment: Currently running from a windows command prompt. Not sure how to set the encoding. I'll have a look and update the question if I find anything

Comment: windows cli and special characters is so scary i always ignored this and hoped it would just go away by itself. gshu gshu!
but i'm pretty sure it's because windows' defautl charset is not ISO-8859-1 but CPsomething (CP850, it think, at least in the german version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0xE9` is the encoding for **é** in iso-8859-1. It's also the unicode codepoint for the same character. If your console interprets output in a different encoding (Such as cp-850), then the same byte will translate to a different codepoint, thus displaying a different character on screen. If you look at [the code page for cp-850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), you can see that the byte `0xE9` translates to **Ú** (Unicode codepoint `0xDA`). So basically your console interprets the bytes wrongly. I'm not sure how, but you should change the charset of your console to iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

Before running your php on the command line, try executing the command:

```
chcp 1252
```

This will change the codepage to one where the accented characters are as you expect.

See the following links for the difference between the 850 and 1252 codepages:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

Answer (score -2):

The accent might be considered unicode data and you will have to store it as such.  Take a look at [`utf_decode`](http://www.php.net/utf_decode), [`utf_encode`](http://www.php.net/utf_encode), and [`iconv`](http://www.php.net/iconv) functions.

No wait, it is in the [ISO 8859-1](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/iso224-255.html) charset.  I don't know.  Have you tried reading in binary mode or using `file_get_contents`?